# What was Nietzsche's influence on Miroslav Krleža?

Tags: friedrich-nietzsche, miroslav-krleza, croatian-language

Miroslav Krleža was one of the most important 20th-century Croatian authors. The [Wikipedia article about him](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Miroslav_Krle%C5%BEa&oldid=962385638#Works) lists several influences on his work, including "key authors like (...) Nietzsche". However, that statement has no source and there is no similar statement (with or without a source) in the [French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Miroslav_Krle%C5%BEa&oldid=171498395) and [German](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Miroslav_Krle%C5%BEa&oldid=201637635) Wikipedia articles about Krleža.

What exactly constituted Friedrich Nietzsche's influence on Miroslav Krleža?

Answer (score 3):

The appropriate citation is to Mirjana Stančić's book *Miroslav Krleža i njemačka književnost* (*Miroslav Krleža and German literature*), in which the first chapter is entitled "Najveci filozofski ucitelj epohe i njegov ucenik. Krleza i Nietzsche" (The greatest philosophical teacher of the era and his student. Krleza and Nietzsche). Unfortunately, [this book](https://www.njuskalo.hr/monografije/mirjana-stancic-miroslav-krleza-njemacka-knjizevnost-oglas-29915699) is written in Croatian and doesn't seem to have been translated into English (I don't know if translations into other languages exist).

[image]

I found this via [Vladimir Biti, *Attached to Dispossession: Sacrificial Narratives in Post-imperial Europe*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=aMZKDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA104&lpg=PA104&dq=nietzsche+krleza&source=bl), which says in Chapter 3, pp. 103-104, that:

> It was now time to redefine the values that remained deeply rooted in the consciousness of the alienated Croatian intelligentsia. To this end, the young Krleža, like other East-Central European intellectuals of his time, enthusiastically employed Friedrich Nietzsche's program of resolutely re-defining all values in the sphere of the politics of the day.

with a footnote citing "Nietzsche's influence on Krleža" to "Stančić 13-50".

There are also some research papers on specific aspects of the connection between Krleza and Nietzsche, such as [Anđela Vidović, "Connections between Nietzsche’s Zarathustra and Krleža’s work on the example of The Days of Long Ago", *Kroatologija: časopis za hrvatsku kulturu* 3.2 (2012)](https://hrcak.srce.hr/index.php?show=clanak&id_clanak_jezik=157766):

> The main intention of this paper is to show evident connections between Nietzsche’s masterpiece *Thus  Spoke  Zarathustra*, and Krleža’s memoir entries *Diary  1914–1917:  The  Days  of  Long Ago  I* and *Diary  1918–1922:  The  Days  of Long Ago II*. The analysis focuses on seven memoir entries from the war period of 1914 – 1918, where *Zarathustra* motifs are observable in Krleža’s writings. It is argued that Krleža’s reading of *Zarathustra* is unsystematic, impulsive and emotional, as well as that there are obvious contrasts in his interpretation: aesth/etics, life/death, creation/demolition, ecstasy/skepticism. Intimate readings of young Krleža show how he combines a close/distant relationship towards his mentor in accordance with his own po/ethic (antitetička vrteška).

Although I couldn't find many specific details about Nietzsche's influence on Krleža, it certainly seems to be an established fact that there *was* influence, even to the extent of multiple sources referring to Nietzsche as Krleža's teacher or mentor.